# Ubuntu with LVM and LUKS on external USB HDD + standby = complete crash

Tags: suspend, encryption, usb-drive, lvm

I've installed a kubuntu 16.04.1 on an external USB 3.0 HDD with LVM and LUKS encryption.

I can boot the laptop from the disk and all works very well.

Putting the system to standby however completely thrashed it. The laptop went to standby but after waking it up all running applications behaved extremely erratic and it was not possible to start new applications.

After a restart it first looked normal again but most applications failed and were complaining about the filesystem being readonly.

So I restarted again but after unlocking the filesystem all I got was rescue mode with busybox.

Restarting in recovery mode, I could see the OS refused to mount the filesystem because it was not clean and I was told to run fsck. It reported and fixed countless errors that didn't sound very good.
After that the system started again but there were issues because of missing or broken files and directories.

So the installation is broken. Not a problem, because I did not lose any data and could just try again.

But I wonder if my setup makes sense at all, I suppose it would be necessary to unlock the filesystem again when resuming from standby which is not the case. Maybe hibernate would work but it is disabled, I think I'll enable and try it. If hibernate cannot be used either, I think this setup is not very interesting.

So, is my setup broken or is there something not yet implemented to support such a setup? Would I have to make sure the system never goes to standby if I would use such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone has the same issue...

I tried hibernate with this setup with `sudo pm-hibernate` and it works fine (on a recent DELL laptop).

Then I enabled hibernate and disabled standby (suspend) in the menus as follows:

Create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` with the following content:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Disable standby by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no

[Disable standby by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-suspend-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=no
```

All power management settings in the System Settings are disabled so I set them up as well, using hibernate.

The information that helped me to do this was taken from [How do I hibernate my computer?](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

I'm still not sure if this is a preferred setup but it works fine including hibernate, and now there is no risk to accidentally suspend and thrash the whole installation.